# Stopped working code

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

After update wordpress from old version this code stopped working:

```
<?php ( get_the_term_list(get_the_ID, 'taxonomy_authors','',', ') )? printf( __( '<p class="hentry-tags">%1$s</p>', 'unspoken' ),  get_the_term_list(get_the_ID, 'taxonomy_authors','',', ') ) : ''; ?>
```

What could happen?

Comment: Are you using any custom fields plugin for terms?

Comment: Yes, ACF. But this castom taxonomy, no custom field.

Comment: I asked that because since WP 4.4 custom fields for ***taxonomies*** are now part of the core, which possibly break websites using custom fields for taxonomies.

Comment: Stopped working means... visually different, or broken (error)?

Comment: After deactivate plugin ACF page dont loading. In code interrupted  on: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function the_field() in <b>/var/www/admin/www/anthecology.org/wp-content/themes/anthecology_theme/header.php</b> on line <b>93</b>

Comment: is it possible to renounce the use of ACF? Advise any manual.